# How to mark as selected the default text of multiple textarea on tabindex?

Tags: javascript

I have few textarea on which I want to get the default text selected when I tabbing upon it.
For a single textarea I've found a script which I adapted to my situation but is not an elegant solution.
How can I shorten it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox1 = document.getElementById("textarea_1");
    var textBox2 = document.getElementById("textarea_2");
    var textBox3 = document.getElementById("textarea_3");

    textBox1.onfocus = function() {
        textBox1.select();
        // Work around Chrome's little problem
        textBox1.onmouseup = function() {
            // Prevent further mouseup intervention
            textBox1.onmouseup = null;
            return false;
        };
    };
    textBox2.onfocus = function() {
        textBox2.select();
        textBox2.onmouseup = function() {
            textBox2.onmouseup = null;
            return false;
        };
    };
    textBox3.onfocus = function() {
        textBox3.select();
        textBox3.onmouseup = function() {
            textBox3.onmouseup = null;
            return false;
        };
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a dedicated class name and refactor the code to be more generic using class name as selector an make **it work for multiple `textareas`** like this:

```js
// Add the class 'auto-selectable' to the desired <texarea/> elements
var textBoxes = document.getElementByClassName('auto-selectable');

for(var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {
  var textBox = textBoxes[i];
   
  textBox.select();
  
  // Work around Chrome's little problem
  textBox.onmouseup = function() {
    // Prevent further mouseup intervention
    textBox.onmouseup = null;
    
    return false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a small correction to Plamen's answer: **Elements** not **Element**

```
var textBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('auto-selectable');
```

instead of:

```
var textBoxes = document.getElementByClassName('auto-selectable');
```